# Kendo mobile viewmodel not binding to <DIV>

Tags: kendo-mobile

```
I am not sure what is happening but I am not able to bind my view model to any HTML tags. I want to display values of book variable in my span tag of DIV.

This is my js file

(function () {
    var currentAnswer;
    var AnswerDetail;
    var book2 = {question2:"A", answer2:"B"};
     window.AnswerDetail = {
    show: function () {
        //Pull the ISBN number from the query string
        var location = window.location.toString();
        var id = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('?') + 4);

        // Filter the DataSource bt ISBN to get the selected record
        window.Answers.data.filter({
            field: "id",
            operator: "eq",
            value: id
        });
        currentAnswer = window.Answers.data.view()[0];
        //alert(currentAnswer.question);
        question2 = currentAnswer.question;
        //alert(currentAnswer.answer);
        return(currentAnswer.question);

    },
    hide: function () {
        // When the user navigates away from the page, remove the filter
        window.Answers.data.filter([]);
    }
    ,
    open: function () {
        // When the user navigates away from the page, remove the filter
        question2 = currentAnswer.question;
    }
};
    var book = kendo.observable({
        question2: "Query"
    });
    kendo.bind($(('#bookContent')), book);
}());

This is my HTML file
<div id="AnswerContent2" data-model="book" data-role="view" data-title="Details" data-layout="main" data-show="AnswerDetail.show" data-hide="AnswerDetail.hide" data-reload="true" data-transition="fade">
    <div id="bookContent" data-model="book" data-role="view" >
        <p><span id="q" data-bind="text: question2"></span> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The functions are working perfectly, variables are getting values. But I am not able to create viewmodel  and assign to the DIV. Infact I am facing this issue with all my viewmodel creation and binding to DIV. Please advise.

Comment: I don't think you can have a view nested inside another view like that.

Comment: Have see few examples where they mention nested DIV works. Anyways I did remove the outer div with  id = AnswerContent2, still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a lot of issues here...

Maybe you just forgot to include this in your code, but where do you create the Kendo Mobile Application? Somewhere you should have a call to:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
```

---

Remove the nested 'view's, so changing:

```
<div id="bookContent" data-model="book" data-role="view" >
```

to:

```
<div id="bookContent" >
```

---

You can remove this:

```
kendo.bind($(('#bookContent')), book);
```

because views are already MVVM bound to whatever you specify in the `data-model` attribute. You specify `data-model="book"` but there is no `window.book` variable.

You probably want to make `book` a property on your ViewModel, which I suppose also doesn't exist at the moment. Maybe it should be `book`?

```
window.book = kendo.observable({
    question2: "Query"
});
```

---

Finally, your code sets `question2` in a couple places, but that is not a defined variable, so it is leaking to global scope.

```
question2 = currentAnswer.question; // this becomes window.question2
```

You might want to enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
```

which would detect this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: question2 is not defined

---

See if this working example makes more sense: http://dojo.telerik.com/OxISo